# debugging Subroutine in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am trying to debug my code that involves a subroutine and a module.  I get two error messages from the subroutine : 1) Symbol is not a dummy variable, 2) Legacy Extension : REAL array index.   I indicate in the code where the errors come from.

The main program reads in a file with one column of numbers.  I then CALL the subroutine using this file as the argument.  The sub-routine then gives me these two error messages.  How can I fix my code and thus fix these error messages?  Thanks

Note : I edited the code based on the useful comment below.  I still get the same error messages.

```
MODULE Stack1
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, PARAMETER:: nx = 48, ny = 48

CONTAINS 

SUBROUTINE Stack2

REAL,DIMENSION(-nx:nx,-ny:ny),INTENT(INOUT):: f !produces error message 1)
REAL :: x0,y0,x1,y1,x,y,a0,a1,a2,a3,nstep,dx,dy
INTEGER :: i
DATA x0,x1,y0,y1,nstep/0.d0,1.d0,0.d0,1.d0,10/ 

p(x,y)=a0 +a1*x+a2*y+a3*x*y !interpolant polynomial

!now evaluate the function f on the 4 known grid points
!use this to solve for the unknown interpolant coefficients a0,a1,a2,a3

a0=(f(x0,y0)*x1*y1-f(x1,y0)*x0*y1+(f(x1,y1)*x0-f(x0,y1)*x1)*y0 )/&
(x1*y1-x0*y1+( x0-x1 )*y0 )  !produces error message 2)

a1=(f(x1,y0)*y1-f(x0,y0)*y1+(f(x0,y1)-f(x1,y1))*y0 )/&
(x1*y1-x0*y1+( x0-x1 )*y0 )  !produces error message 2)

a2=(f(x0,y1)*x1-f(x0,y0)*x1+(f(x1,y0)-f(x1,y1))*x0 )/&
(x1*y1-x0*y1+( x0-x1 )*y0 )  !produces error message 2)

a3=(f(x1,y1)-f(x1,y0)-f(x0,y1)+f(x0,y0) )/&
(x1*y1-x0*y1+( x0-x1 )*y0 )  !produces error message 2)

DO i=0,nstep
    x=x0+dx*FLOAT(i)
    y=y0+dy*FLOAT(i)
    y=0.75d0*y1
    print 100,x,y,p(x,y),f(x,y)
    20 continue
    100 format('x,y,p,f=',4(3x,e10.3))
END DO

END SUBROUTINE  Stack2

END MODULE Stack1

PROGRAM StackProblem

USE Stack1

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: i,j
REAL,DIMENSION(-nx:nx,-ny:ny) :: Func

OPEN(UNIT=11, file='TestFile1.dat',status='old')

    DO i=-nx,nx
    DO j=-ny,ny
     
        READ(11,*) Func(i,j)
 
    END DO
    END DO

CALL Stack2(Func)

END PROGRAM StackProblem
```

Note, the file TestFile1.dat is just a single column file with real numbers in it, for ex:

```
1.30482
1.30787
1.31098
1.32983
```

Comment: *I am trying to debug my code that involves a subroutine and a module* First, insert `implicit none` right after the `module` line and get the compiler to check for a common source of errors.  Personally I think you're wasting your time developing code without that safety harness; you can probably guess my thinking on my time too :-)

Comment: You are missing the dummy argument in the subroutine statement.  You should have `subroutine stack2(f)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll address your error messages first. Then I'll point out a few other problems I see and try to suggest how you might choose to pursue a solution.

1. Error 1: **Symbol is not a dummy variable.** This is because the subroutine `stack2` is called with an argument in the program `stackproblem`. However, `stack2` has no arguments in its definition. Simply declaring the variable `f` with `intent(inout)` is not sufficient, and should probably result in other error messages.
2. Error 2: **Legacy Extension: REAL array index.** Note that `f` from the module `stack1` is declared to be a 2D array of `real` values. Of course, each element within the array may be accessed using `f(row,col)` where `row` is the row number and `col` is the column number. Furthermore, `row,col` should be integers. However, in the subroutine `stack2` you are accessing elements of the array using `real` values. I believe the fundamental problem is that you are treating `f` like it is a function - but it is not.

Now, you don't mention any other issues but there appear to be other problems and misunderstandings. Here is one:

- The variable (?) function (?) `p` is not declared/defined. Since you have used `implicit none` this should also cause a compiler error.

Comment: p is a statement function - an archaic bit of syntax which nowadays should be avoided. Here a contained subprogram would do the job.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You’ve certainly pointed out the mistakes but can you suggest a solution as to how to fix this? I’m looking for a solution too. Thanks

Comment: @Ian Bush THanks for pointing out the old notation. How can I implement a subprogram? Thanks